# Why is SQL Server 2008 change tracking table not being cleaned up after hotfix has been applied?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We seem to have the issue listed here with no Service Packs applied:

FIX: The sys.syscommittab system table is not cleaned up after the retention period for change tracking in SQL Server 2008 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2446860)

So we've applied SP2 and then SP2 Cumulative Update 2 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2467239) which lists that it includes the fix for the issue.  However, we are still seeing the issue.  Does anyone have any suggestions on what we might have done wrong or if there is another known issue?

We installed the SP and CU to just one development instances on the server.  Does it need to be applied to all?  Is there some other step we need to follow to tell SQL Server to clean up change tracking now?  We've tried querying with the change tracking functions and also changed the retention period.  We've also even tried with a new database.  Still the sys.syscommittab table is not cleaned up.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seemed like you had to get the clean up process going by forcing some updates.  Otherwise some clean seemed to happen, but not much.  Now our test environments appear to be cleaning up.